# Array filter is returning data very slowly

Tags: arrays, wcf, knockout.js, wcf-rest

I am using knockout arrayfilter to filter items. But if there are more than 1000 records then it returns data very slowly. What should i do for it? Here is my method

```
viewModel.filteredData = ko.computed(function () {
var str = "<temp>";
if (viewModel.selection() == "All") return viewModel.dataOne();
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.dataOne(), function (data) {
    stringFromArray = data.display;
    if (stringFromArray.indexOf(str) == 0) {
        return true;
    }

   });
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byJ5x/8/)

When i select option button "All" then it will load all the data and if i select "Selected" then it will filter record. Right now i dont have much records in my fiddle so its filtering pretty fast. 
But in my real life application i have more than 5000 records and it takes 10 seconds to show All records. What i mean is i load data from my service and data is loaded and option button "All" is selected.
Then i select "Selected" option button which filters record in 3-5 seconds. Now when i again click on "All" option button then it takes 10 seconds to reload data. How could i improve speed.

I also read about question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880015/knockout-performance-filtering-an-observable-array) but was not able to understand it.

**Update1**

I have decided to do server side paging. Can someone give me links to do server side paging using kogrid? I am using WCF services to retrieve data. Do i need to pass pagesize parameter to service everytime when its called. Do let me know if there is any example using kogrid with wcf service.

Comment: doesn't look like it is the array filter that is an issue here. It is the rendering of that large amount of data that would be your bottle neck. I have a fiddle with over 2600 items. I put a couple of timers in there to see how much time it is taking. The array filter is taking only 2 ms and the "All" wouldnt even hit your arraFilter, even that is taking under 1 ms. Rendering that amount of data, will definitely slow things down. Page the data, put a limit (say 10 at a time and see how things are).

Comment: @sujesharukil should i do client side paging or server side?

Comment: server side would be more beneficial, since this is really large chunk of data that you are pulling down, which is expensive.

Comment: @sujesharukil can you recomend some good links for server side paging?

Comment: @SujeshArukil i have updated quesion

Comment: There are a ton of articles and tutorials available on the net for this. Just google it (I would have to do the same to provide you the links). At this point, your update is completely different than your original question or problem.

Comment: @sujesharukil i really was not able to find article using kogrid with wcf service. Do let me know. I decided to use server side paging as client side paging was not helpful and hence updated question

Comment: I have put a couple of links in the answer section. I have not worked with KoGrid and not in a position to give you links or direction there. However, I have provided a pure Knockout implementation of a paged grid. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be this link here will help you..

[Iterating through a list of users and pushing to an array in knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973337/iterating-through-a-list-of-users-and-pushing-to-an-array-in-knockout/15975378#15975378)

This is how you would set up your viewmodel to enable paging.

And this link here

[Make a WCF Service Accept JSON Data from jQuery.AJAX()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530412/make-a-wcf-service-accept-json-data-from-jquery-ajax/15530687#15530687)

would help you get your WCF service work. Of course, the data would be the paging data from the first link.

Comment: So as per your first link i dont need to create any parameter in wcf service for sending pagenumber? So when i make call to service it will return me all data? If i get all data from server at once then does it mean server side paging?

Comment: Not true. Those links are just an example of how you can set up paging to show up. You will still be passing your currentPageNumber, totalRecordsToReturn and totalRecords (in your database). This you can package in to a DTO (model, POCO) that will be passed in with each paging request. The return from the server (WCF service) should be arrayOfRecords, totalRecords (in your database). Based on these two values, you can show your grid. Hope that helps.